# Is it possible in theory to generate the private key for the 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 wallet?

Tags: wallets, ether, accounts, private-key

Is there any chance, although extremely low, to generate the private key for the 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 wallet? Does the system allow it at all?

Answer (score 5):

This type of attractive address names called `vanity addresses` and you can use https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/VanityEth to generate them. If you are very very very lucky one day you'll get it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible in theory, but the probability of generating the private key for the 0x0 address (and any others) is:

[image: probability]

> Near enough to zero you could [convert the entire solar system to a computer](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/88s6qu/account_0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000/dwmy8bm/?context=8&depth=9) and try until the end of the universe and never succeed.

Yes, the protocol allows it: the protocol does not have any special treatment that prevents the zero address from operating like all other addresses if its private key was found.

Comment: Actually most of ERC-20 tokens are coded to block transfers from the zero address, so I guess you could only transfer ETH and few more
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

Comment: @Xriuk Good comment and I will clarify that the answer is about the protocol. (There are token implementations before or do not use the code you reference.)