# Who has access to ethereum 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 address?

Tags: genesis, airdrop

Who own ethereum 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 address? I have received some 0Chain token from this address. I know this is a genesis address but who can access it?

Comment: No one has the private key for that address. When new coins are minted, they typically show as being `Transfer`red from address 0.

Comment: Then how I have received tokens from this address? You can check the address here https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000#tokentxns . There are so many transactions out there. If no one has access then transactions are going out from this address? Is this actually "genesis address" or a contract registration address?

Comment: For the reason I said. The link you sent is to "token transfers," which are in no way transactions. Those are `Transfer` events emitted by smart contracts to indicate that new coins were minted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a treasure trove of tokens sent to `address(0)` to "burn" under the assumption that no one has the private key. *and no one ever will*.

In a manner of speaking, I would classify it as a very large open bounty. It's like a pinata for mathematicians and quantum computers.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Ethereum address that contains empty zero bytes is also known as *zero-address*. It is also the address specified to create a new contract. So it might also probably contain the ether / gas paid each time that a new smart contract was deployed on the blockchain.

Comment: Gas for contract deployment goes to the miner. It's a purgatory where people send things to demonstrate they are notionally destroyed.

Answer (score 7):

The genesis block is a special block which was mined by nobody and therefore is associated with the account 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

It's impossible to generate the private key for this address and people can use it as proof-of-burn account on the Ethereum blockchain.

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing in Ethereum preventing someone from using the private key for the address; it is just unlikely that someone will generate it at random and it is currently infeasible to perform intentionally. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16768/is-it-possible-in-theory-to-generate-the-private-key-for-the-0x00000000000000000

Comment: Agree with @lungj. (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37221/if-someone-found-a-private-key-to-0x0-would-they-be-able-to-access-all-the-toke) I'm assuming it's used as a proof-of-burn address because it acts as a Schelling point, or because people are under the false assumption that it's impossible to generate the private key that maps to it.

Comment: You can generate private key for  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  same as any other account: 1 in 2^160 per attempt.  *Near enough to zero you could convert the entire solar system to a computer and try until the end of the universe and never succeed.*  https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/88s6qu/account_0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000/dwmy8bm

Comment: The private key has 256 bits, not 160.  The address is 160 bits from the public key.  But yeah it would be impossibly hard, that's true ;)

Answer (score -3):

It is not only that you cannot generate this key, but you cannot sign anything with it since its value is literally 0. if you try to sign a signature with the value 0 you will not get a valid signature because standard public keys are within a certain integer limit .
For example here is secp256k https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1.
When you replace the values of the public key with 0 values it is basically as if the signature was signed by anybody or the polar opposite, nobody. Even if it was easy to generate this type of key it's signature output should not be accepted as valid, the logic should be basically that simple.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140137/discussion-on-answer-by-poseidon-who-has-access-to-ethereum-0x000000000000000000).